# How to configure GPU to work in TCC mode on Windows 10?

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, matlab

I'm using Windows 10, and I want my GPU to dedicate itself to computing, instead of graphics. Here is the information on MATLAB:

```
>> gpuDevice

ans = 

  CUDADevice with properties:

                      Name: 'Quadro M1000M'
                     Index: 1
         ComputeCapability: '5.0'
            SupportsDouble: 1
             DriverVersion: 8
            ToolkitVersion: 7.5000
        MaxThreadsPerBlock: 1024
          MaxShmemPerBlock: 49152
        MaxThreadBlockSize: [1024 1024 64]
               MaxGridSize: [2.1475e+09 65535 65535]
                 SIMDWidth: 32
               TotalMemory: 2.1475e+09
           AvailableMemory: 1.6915e+09
       MultiprocessorCount: 4
              ClockRateKHz: 1071500
               ComputeMode: 'Default'
      GPUOverlapsTransfers: 1
    KernelExecutionTimeout: 1
          CanMapHostMemory: 1
           DeviceSupported: 1
            DeviceSelected: 1
```

And here the result when I went to C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVSMI\ and used the command line:

```
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVSMI>nvidia-smi.exe -L
GPU 0: Quadro M1000M (UUID: GPU-10af5042-4cf4-0ad4-a314-abc9b616b1a8)
```

Tried the instructions on this site: https://blogs.fau.de/johanneshabich/2010/12/10/windows-and-cuda-enabling-tcc-with-nvidia-smi/

```
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVSMI>nvidia-smi -g 0 -dm 1
Unable to set driver model for GPU 0000:01:00.0: Not Supported
Treating as warning and moving on.
All done
```

How can I fix this? I really need to use the GPU in computing mode only . Please help me, thank you very much :)

Comment: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/959472/how-to-know-what-cards-allow-tcc-mode-/

Comment: Ok, so it says that a GPU cannot activate TCC mode if it's working on display. But I have only 1 GPU, and it seems like Windows 10 is using it for graphics, but I'm unable to change it :( . Tried googling but no results :(

Comment: Do you have a display connected to the GPU? TCC mode cannot be enabled if a display is connected. You can use -fdm instead of -dm to force your way through.

Comment: Quadro M1000M is a laptop GPU, and will probably always have the laptop's display attached to it. Maybe you can set up VNC, and disable laptop's display somehow, and then access laptop over VNC.

Comment: I'm sorry but it has been more than a year since I asked this question, and now I do not own that machine anymore :(

Comment: @SahilSingh, if the gpu not connected with the display, how can I see the user interface? I tried to disconnect one gpu from display and `nvidia-smi -g 1 -fdm 1`,  still same error as mentioned

Answer (score 3):

Hello Dang Manh Truong!

If you wish to use your Quadro GPU strictly for computing, I recommend NVidia NSight Monitor. Once you open it as administrator, you can find in the properties section two interesting settings:
a) WDDM which is set by default to true
b) WDDM timeout in milliseconds

Setting WDDM to false will deactivate that Windows Watchdog and will enable you to use your GPU however you wish. But be cautious: your screen may freeze. Not to worry, it will unfreeze once it's done with its computation.

If you wish to avoid screen freeze you can increase WDDM timeout by setting that value to a higher one. This would, of course, require code optimization to fit within the time frame.

One other thing you could do is right click on the desktop and open NVidia Control panel. There, at the 3d Settings Section you will have the "Configure SLI, Surround,PhysX" settings. If you open it, you will see that the PhysX processor is set (by default) to Auto-select. And the OS of course selects the GPU to render your display. Set it to CPU. Now your display will be processed by the CPU.

One last thing, GeForce cards do not support TCC, only WDDM. Quadro I believe supports both so there might be a way to set it to TCC if this is what you want, but it will be useless.. The Quadro version you have cannot be set in that mode. You can read more from this link:
https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/513659/can-tcc-mode-be-enabled-with-quadro-2000m-4000m/

Hope it helps. Best of luck ;)

ps. Use TechPowerUp GPU-Z for real-time gpu resource monitoring

Answer (score 2):

For windows, open command window as administrator

Enter the following command:

```
nvidia-smi -g 0 -fdm 1
```

Reboot

Comment: It still says `Unable to set driver model for GPU 00000000:01:00.0: Not Supported
Treating as warning and moving on.
All done.`

Answer (score 0):

How do I undo this command?

For windows, open command window as administrator

Enter the following command:

nvidia-smi -g 0 -fdm 1
Reboot

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Reboot is not a nvidia-smi command on Windows